# Compare two objects by making a method

Tags: java

Following the Oracle Acadamy Java Fundamentals and I walked into a wall(I dont understand how its explained in the acadamy)

The Try It/Solve It:

> 7. Create a method `nicestFish` that takes in two fish as parameters, compares the friendliness level of two fish, and returns the fish with the higher friendliness. Test this method with the fish defined in problem 6.

Main:

```
public class index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish Amber = new Fish("AngelFish", 5);
        Fish James = new Fish("Guppy", 3);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Fish {
    String typeOfFish;
    int friendliness;

    public Fish(){
        typeOfFish = "unknown";
        friendliness = 3;
    }

    public Fish(String t, int f) {
        this.typeOfFish = t;
        this.friendliness = f;
    }

    public int getFriendliness(){
        return friendliness;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have you at least tried declaring the  nicestFish method? What do you think it should do?

Comment: Are you looking for `compareTo` method ?

Comment: Im not sure how to proceed with making the method for comparinson. I dont know how to call/get the value of the friendliness value from Amber and James. I do know how to use compareto

Comment: So you're in problem 7 of some kind of tutorial and "it"/"they" never showed you how to access fields of an object?

Comment: You get the friendliness of a fish by saying "fish, get friendliness" in Javaese: `fish.getFriendliness()`

Comment: @laune LOL, It's *Friend*-liness, not *Fiend*-liness. Exact opposite meaning.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks - this gag wasn't intended.

Comment: @laune Figured as much, but it was funny how a simple typo could totally reverse the meaning. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing they want you to make a static comparison method, since they specify it takes two Fish as arguments

```
public class Fish
{
...
    public static Fish nicestFish(Fish f1, Fish f2)
    { 
        //find out which fish is nicest, and return it
    }
...
}
```

To call a static method, you do not need an object reference:

```
Fish fish1 = ...
Fish fish2 = ...
Fish nicest = Fish.nicestFish(fish1, fish2);
```

Comment: Good start, and great teaching tool of not providing full solution. Thumbs Up (and vote up).